# How to pass data to SQL query within Laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel

I just want to pull some statistics from database I do this query:

```
    $merchant = Auth::guard('merchant')->user()->id;

    $statistics =  DB::select(DB::raw(
        "SELECT
        (SELECT SUM(billing_total) FROM orders WHERE merchant_id = :merchant) as sales,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders WHERE merchant_id = :merchant) as orders,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products WHERE merchant_id = :merchant) as products,

        "), array(
        'merchant' => $merchant,
      ));
```

First one to sum `billing_total`  in orders table when `merchant_id` like the merchant which is auth now! and other queries same concept

The error that I got:

```
064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT SUM(billing_total) AS total FROM ' at line 2 (SQL: SELECT SELECT SUM(billing_total) AS total FROM orders WHERE merchant_id = :merchant -- (SELECT SUM(billing_total) FROM orders WHERE merchant_id = :merchant) as sales, -- (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders WHERE merchant_id = :merchant) as orders, -- (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products WHERE merchant_id = :merchant) as products, )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you many use the variable directly like this:

```
 $merchant = Auth::guard('merchant')->user()->id;

        $statistics =  DB::select(DB::raw(
            "SELECT
        (SELECT SUM(billing_total) FROM orders WHERE merchant_id ={$merchant}) as sales,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders WHERE merchant_id = {$merchant}) as orders,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products WHERE merchant_id = {$merchant}) as products,

        "));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use model instead of DB class like this:

```php
$sales = {order_model}::where('merchant_id', $merchant)->sum('billing_total');
$orders = {order_model}::where('merchant_id', $merchant)->count();
$products = {product_model}::where('merchant_id', $merchant)->count();
```

Comment: I know that but I like sql cuz it's faster than model and all of these in one query!

Comment: Did you try `?` instead of :merchant ?

Comment: Yeah same thing!